# Build a graph recursively - breadth first

Tags: python, recursion, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

i want to build a "graph" in the following style:

```
{
"name":cersei
"children": [
    {
        "name": "baratheon", 
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "cersei",
                "children": []
            }, 
            {
                "name": "baratheon",
                "children": [],
            }
        ], 
    }, 
    {
        "name": "joffrey", 
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "robert", 
                "children": []   
            }, 
            {
                "name": "cersei", 
                "children": []
            }
        ]            
    }
]
}
```

But i build this via depth-first. That means the first element of "children" is fully build, after that the second element of "children" is build. This is the recurse-function:

```
def recurse(dicts, depth):
    if depth >=0:
        dicts["children"] = []
    child_elements = [] //do something to get your child-elements
    for child in child_elements:
        if depth >=0:
            child_dict = dict(name=word[0])
            dicts["children"].append(child_dict)
            recurse(child_dict, depth-1)
```

How can i change the code that it builds the whole "level" first and appends the childrens-children later?  I've got the problem, that i don't know how to call the level 1 dictionary, because its kind of a dictionary in the dictionary...

Kind regards and thanks for your help, FFoDWindow.

--------------------****UPDATE****---------------------------
I solved the issue myself. Actually it was pretty simple. I only had to save the temporarly build "children"-elements in an extra list. Now the tree is build breadth-first. Here is my recurse function:

```
def recurse( input_dict, level_list, depth):
     next_level_list = []
     for dictionary in input_dict:
           child_elements = [...] //get the data for your children
           for child_element in child_elements:
               dictionary["children"].append = dict(name = child_element)
               next_level_list.append(dictionary["children"][-1])
      if depth >=0:
           recurse(input_dict, next_level_list, depth-1)
```

Comment: You `GRAPH["children"][0]["level"] == 2`right?` I am not clear what you are stuck with: Knowing how to build a "deep" dict[key][other_key][...] query or would you like us to rewrite your code? Please advice / clarify. Thanks. And it would be great to have working code, for how you built this above sample data structure (the actual call to the recurse() function I guess and the input data). But maybe I just do not see it.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. My issue is a little hard to describe - i need to delete all the double children and to resolve this issue i need to build the tree breadth-first. Now it is depth-first. I'm asking for some tips how to rewrite my code. Is there an easy solution to implement a breadth-first build from this code? I will provide a working example tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it myself this morning? Is anyone interested in my code?

Comment: Yes of course. You may well edit your answer, with a visible **Update** section, so other people receive help when trapped themselves in there. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my question. Thank you eitherway!